# Make a new array using regex to find elements starting with A through J

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, dictionary, arrow-functions

```
let cityList = ['Clevelend', 'Birmingham', 'Austin', 'Milwaukee'];

citiesAtoJ = arr => {
    console.log(arr.map( () => { /\b[A-J].*?/g} ));
};

citiesAtoJ(cityList);
```

I know I need to use a function with map but I'm kinda lost.

Answer (score 2):

`.map` will construct a new array with the same number of elements as the old array - but you want to only include elements that pass the test. Use `.filter` instead:

```js
let cityList = ['Clevelend', 'Birmingham', 'Austin', 'Milwaukee'];

const citiesAtoJ = arr => arr.filter(
  city => /\b[A-J]/.test(city)
);

console.log(citiesAtoJ(cityList));
```